# Как установить scipy с использованием pip?

Tags: python, pip, library, python-3.8, scipy

Я уже пробовал методы обновления pip и wheel или же пробовать python3 -m pip install -U scipy, но все равно одна и та же ошибка и после чего pip пытается установить более старую версию scipy, в установке каждой старой версии такая же ошибка:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.7.1.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3.8 /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/tmpi_3djphe
         cwd: /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-install-kehr6ukt/scipy_5aee14ac6e9e472d9bbf7d9b914100b5
    Complete output (167 lines):
    Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
    Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
    Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
    Processing scipy/spatial/_hausdorff.pyx
    Processing scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx
    Processing scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx
    Processing scipy/spatial/_voronoi.pyx
    Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
    Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
    Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
    Processing scipy/spatial/transform/rotation.pyx
    Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio_utils.pyx
    Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx
    Processing scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx
    Processing scipy/special/cython_special.pyx
    Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx
    Processing scipy/special/_test_round.pyx
    Processing scipy/special/_comb.pyx
    Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx
    Processing scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx
    Processing scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.pyx
    Processing scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx
    Processing scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx
    Processing scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx
    Processing scipy/signal/_upfirdn_apply.pyx
    Processing scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx
    Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
    Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
    Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx
    Processing scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx
    Processing scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx
    Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/_stats.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/biasedurn.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx
    Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
    Processing scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.pyx
    Processing scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx
    Processing scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx
    Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
    Processing scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:9:8: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:13:4: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:21:8: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:25:4: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:33:8: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:37:4: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:45:8: Unreachable code
    warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:49:4: Unreachable code
    Processing scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in
    Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
    Processing scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx
    Processing scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx
    Processing scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx
    Processing scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in
    Processing scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx
    Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx
    Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx
    Processing scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx.in
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_matching.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx
    Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_flow.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    setup.py:490: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-modern-metadata-pjt10_0b'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
    Running from SciPy source directory.
    /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-fj65f4s5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-fj65f4s5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
        main()
      File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 151, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-fj65f4s5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 166, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-fj65f4s5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 258, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-fj65f4s5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 629, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 625, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-fj65f4s5/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "setup.py", line 528, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError(msg)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found.
    To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
    See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/33/a24aec22b7be7fdb10ec117a95e1e4099890d8bbc6646902f443fc7719d1/scipy-1.7.1.tar.gz#sha256=6b47d5fa7ea651054362561a28b1ccc8da9368a39514c1bbf6c0977a1c376764 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/) (requires-python:>=3.7,<3.10). Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3.8 /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/tmpi_3djphe Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что делать в таком случае? Помогите пожалуйста...

Если что версия Python у меня 3.8

Comment: А вот о том, что у вас ARM и Pydroid 3, вы зря решили не рассказывать

Comment: Значит никак не получится установить библиотеку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за своих особенностей Pydroid3 имеет свою библиотеку перекомпилированных пакетов, чтобы установить scipy надо использовать её:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(не помню точно, но Pydroid3 может предложить установить другое приложение - которое уже работает с этими перекомпилированными пакетами)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего больше не трогаем, ждём пока установится и готово!

---

Также возможно установить по-другому:

тут точно Pydroid3 должен попросить о приложении, устанавливаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опять же, ничего больше не трогаем, ждём пока установится и готово!

Comment: @play если вам помог или понравится этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)